# Recommended books about vorticity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow, vortex

Could anyone suggest a good introductory book or any online resource about [vorticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity)?

I just now started to learn physics but I have a good mathematical background.

Comment: "Les principes de la philosophie"  or "Principles of philosophy -1644 Descartes,. It's a bit dated and I've only read the part about Descartes' vortex gravity which was a fun exercise in thought

Answer (score 1):

Vorticity and Incompressible Flow - Andrew J. Majda, New York University Andrea L. Bertozzi, Duke University, North Carolina

The above one is pretty much for beginners, with a good mathematical background it is good for you.

After reading this you may also read the book 'Vorticity and Vortex Dynamics by  Jie-Zhi Wu, Hui-Yang Ma, Ming-De Zhou', it's not much introductory. It is based the old experiments and research done.